# How to download a attachment in browser using JSForce?

Tags: rest-api, lightning-web-components, attachment, jsforce, chatter-api

I am trying to download a Attachment using JSForce library. I am able to get body of attachment and download that file but somehow content of downloaded file is not correct and I am getting a corrupt downloaded file.

```
           var conn = new jsforce.Connection({
               accessToken: `${this.sessionId}`
           });            
           let query = 'select id, body, name from attachment where id = \'00P1g000005A1mT\'';
            conn.query(query, function(err, res) {
                console.log(res.records[0]);
                if(res) {
                   conn.chatter.resource(res.records[0].Body).retrieve(function(err,body) {
                        var l = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(body)));
                        var blob = new Blob(l, {type: "image/jpeg"});
                        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        const a = document.createElement('a');
                        a.style.display = 'none';
                        a.href = url;
                        a.download = 'todo-1.jpg';
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                            alert('your file has downloaded!'); 
                    })
                 }
               })
```

I am running above method in a LWC component. File downloaded is corrupted. I think mistake I am making is somehow how I am converting body to blob but I am not able to figure it out. I also tried getting body of attachment using stream

```
var stream = conn.sobject('Attachment').record(res.records[0].Id).blob('Body');
                    var result = [];
                    stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
                        result.push(chunk);
                        console.log(chunk);
                    });

                    stream.on('end', function () {

                    });
```

But **Stream.on(** events is not getting fired. Sometime 'data' event fires but end event don't fire ever.

Comment: trying this. window.URL is showing as undefined for me,, its lwc right?

Comment: yes it is LWC only

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies here

```
new Blob(l, {type: "image/jpeg"});
```

Blob constructor needs first parameter as byte array where as in your example you are providing it as base64 encoded string. 
Now you have to convert the base64 encoded string to byte array.

I tried to update your code and after converting the base64 into byte array it seems to be working.

Here is the code which you can just run in console:

```
const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType='', sliceSize=512) => {
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  const byteArrays = [];

  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}

function downloadFile(){
    var l = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='  
  var blob = b64toBlob('','image/png');
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'todo-1.png';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  console.log('Downloading file');
}


window.onload = onLoad();
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript

Comment: HI Kiran I am not sure that whether I am getting a string or a blob from response. Above code doesn't work for body I am getting from response. atob method is failing with error "the string to be decoded contains character outside of latin 1 range"

Comment: You will get string in base64 format.

Comment: Give it a try, update your code considering you are getting base64 and see how this works.

Comment: Yes I gave it a try .. it is not working

Comment: @ManjotSingh Kiran, it looks like we are not getting base64 string, but getting a Binary file as a string.

Comment: Let me reproduce this end to end..my general assumption was Salesforce uses base64 in APIs for binary data so that data stays intact.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar
I tried to console.log(), and the output is the same as opening PDF in a text editor like notepad. On top of my head, JSFORCE , somewhere JS force is converting  Binary Blob to string. This issue from 2015 confirms. https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/issues/223

Comment: Hi, I am working on an implementation to fetch EventLogFiles to my node app using jsforce. I am unable to make a GET request to a resource. Can you please help me in figuring out what is wrong? I get a TypeError stating 'request' is not a function under Connection object.
My question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312932/jsforce-get-request-issue